# creating a named range on a pivot field

Tags: excel, vba

For specific reasons, I need to use a named range on a pivot table filter field. I know that the filter field has it's own name, but I need to reference it using a named range. My problem is that all I receive is a list of named ranges to act as parameters and I don't know if they reference a pivot table filter or not. They may be a simple cell. My code needs to use this named range to set the value to a user specified value. This seems to work when the filter is not dates. However, if the filter is a list of dates, and I try to set it by doing

```
Set wbReport = Workbooks.Open(flpath)
wbReport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("myrange").value = "2019/06/01"
```

I get the error `2019/06/01 is not an item of this field`.
I know that I could set it with currentPage of the pivot table filter, but I don't have the pivot table info available to me, and I don't know how/if I can get it via the named range.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution. I am fully aware that this is certainly not the best way to go about it. Any comments / better ideas welcomed :)

```
RangeAddr = Sheet1.Range("MyRange").Cells.Column & ":" & Sheet1.Range("MyRange").Cells.Row
For Each pt In Sheet1.PivotTables
    For Each f In pt.PageFields
        If (f.DataRange.Cells.Column & ":" & f.DataRange.Cells.Row) = RangeAddr Then
            For Each pi In f.PivotItems
                If Format(pi.Value, "yyyy/mm/dd") = UserValue Then
                    f.CurrentPage = pi.Caption
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Exit For
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Basically, what I'm doing here is getting the column and row of my named range. I then loop through all the pivot tables on the sheet, and within that loop through each pageField (filter) on that pivot table. I cross reference the column/row of the pageField against the column/row of my named range.

If they match, I loop through each item of that filter (i.e. the dropdown) and check the value of each against the user specified value. If they match, I set CurrentPage to that PivotItem.